# How to convert bounding box to instance segmentation in COCO.json?

Tags: python, json, segmentation-fault, conv-neural-network, training-data

I have labeled 2 types of objects in images, one object with polygons, the others with bounding boxes and saved the output to COCO format.

When trying to train the model, I run into a KeyError: "segmentation" caused ,as far as I understand, by the bounding boxes not having segmentation values:

```
#For vizualizing
    534         if annos:
    535             if "segmentation" in annos[0]:
--> 536                 masks = [x["segmentation"] for x in annos]
    537             else:
    538                 masks = None

KeyError: 'segmentation'

#For training
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/data/detection_utils.py", line 386, in <listcomp>
    segms = [obj["segmentation"] for obj in annos]
KeyError: 'segmentation'
```

When looking further into the annotation file the following seem to raise the error:

```
{'id': 2334, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': {'size': [2941, 4904], 'counts': 'Q\\ge25[k2\\2dLlMdXMn2ff2e1\\Oc0[Od0WOg0XOf0D<D;E;E;E9G:F9H8G8I8J6J5K6J5K5L4K5L3M4M2M3M4L3M3N2M3M3N3L3M3N2M3M3N2M3M3N2M3N2M2O2N2N2M3N1N3N2M3N2N2M3N2M3N1N3N2M3N2M3N1O2M3N2N2N2M2O2N2N2N2N1O2N2N2N3M2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2M3N1O2N2N2N101N2N2N1O2N2O0O2N2N2N101N2N1O2O1N1O2N2N101N2N1O2O0O2N1O2N1O2O0O2N1O2N1O2N1O2O0O2N1O2N100O2N1O2O0O2N101N1O101N1O101N1O101N1O2O0O1O2N100O2N1O101N1O2N100O2N101N1O101N1O2N101N2N101N1O2O0O2N2O0O2N101N1O2O0O2N101N1O2O0O101N1O2O0O1O2O0O1O2N100O2N1O101N1O101N101N1O101N100O2N101N100O2N101N1O2O0O1O2O0O2N1O101N1O1O2O0O1O2N1O100O2O0O100O100O100O2O0O100O10000O101N100O10000O10000O101N10000O100O10000O10000O100O10000O100O10000O10000O10000000000O10000000O0100000000O100000000O01000000000000O1000O1000O1000000O100000000O1000000O1000000O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O101N101N1O101N101N100O2O0O2O0O101N100O2O0O101N101N100O2N100O2N101N100O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O101N101O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O000O2O0O2O0O2O000O2O0O2O0O2O0O101N101O0O2O0O2O0O2N101N2O0O2N101N2O0O2N2O0O2O1N101N2N101N2O0O2O1N101N2O0O2O1N101N101N2O0O2O0O2O0O2O1N101N101N101N101N1O2O0O2N2O0O2N1O2O0O2N2N101N1O2O1N1O2O1N1O2O1N1O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O001N101N2N101N101N101N101N2O0O2N2O1N1O2N2N2O1N2N1O2N2N2N2O1N2N1O2N2N2O1N2N2N2N2N101N1O101N101N1O1O2O0O2N100O2N101N1O2N100O2N1O2N101N2N2N2N2N2M3N2N3M2N2N2N3M2M4M3M2N3L4M2N3L3N3M2M3N3L3N2N2N2M3N2N2N1O2N2N2N2N2N3M2N2N2N2N2M3N3M2N2N2N2M3N3M3L4L4L4L4L6J6J6J6J6J5J7H8G9G:F9G9H9E:G>A`0@`0@`0[Oe0ZOe0WOf]nS9'}, 'area': 414986, 'bbox': [955, 125, 696, 768], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2335, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': {'size': [2941, 4904], 'counts': 'b__k0Y3Xg2k1kNR1lNo0TOl0_Oa0@>F6G:F:E: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>B:E;F:D=D<D=B>B>B>B>B>Ag0oNP`kR;'}, 'area': 371290, 'bbox': [306, 235, 644, 732], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2336, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[1292, 1003, 1222, 1479, 1232, 1937, 1467, 2048, 1809, 2071, 2054, 1923, 2257, 1683, 2142, 1239, 1842, 1045, 1467, 948]], 'area': 903055.5, 'bbox': [1222, 948, 1035, 1123], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2337, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[1250, 1225, 1269, 1036, 1167, 971, 978, 939, 682, 1087, 543, 1299, 562, 1553, 488, 1923, 659, 2048, 774, 2089, 1061, 2052, 1213, 2020, 1222, 1900]], 'area': 713928.0, 'bbox': [488, 939, 781, 1150], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2338, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[377, 321, 142, 453, 156, 782, 401, 965, 711, 796, 726, 448]], 'area': 279802.0, 'bbox': [142, 321, 584, 644], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2339, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 161734, 'bbox': [3915, 358, 419, 386], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2340, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 257184, 'bbox': [2810, 340, 564, 456], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2341, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 232545, 'bbox': [1954, 382, 555, 419], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2342, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 267486, 'bbox': [862, 387, 654, 409], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2343, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 107442, 'bbox': [448, 1417, 381, 282], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2344, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 190365, 'bbox': [1135, 1403, 555, 343], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2345, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 222318, 'bbox': [2193, 1379, 621, 358], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2346, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 162800, 'bbox': [3285, 1375, 550, 296], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2347, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 167520, 'bbox': [4240, 1393, 480, 349], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2348, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 212954, 'bbox': [3859, 2250, 574, 371], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2349, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 271780, 'bbox': [2810, 2278, 635, 428], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2350, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 239841, 'bbox': [1822, 2316, 729, 329], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2351, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 238770, 'bbox': [890, 2330, 758, 315], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2352, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': None, 'area': 103834, 'bbox': [274, 2334, 386, 269], 'iscrowd': 0}
```

Category_id 1 is annotated with polygons and shows segmentation values, whereas Category_id 2 is annotated with bounding boxes and shows Segmentation: None.

I have tried to replace the segmentation with the bounding boxes but keep receiving the same error:

```
#Segmentation is not found in the bounding boxes
for i in d["annotations"]:
  if i["segmentation"] == None:
    i["segmentation"] = [i["bbox"]]

{'id': 2334, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': {'size': [2941, 4904], 'counts': 'Q\\ge25[k2\\2dLlMdXMn2ff2e1\\Oc0[Od0WOg0XOf0D<D;E;E;E9G:F9H8G8I8J6J5K6J5K5L4K5L3M4M2M3M4L3M3N2M3M3N3L3M3N2M3M3N2M3M3N2M3N2M2O2N2N2M3N1N3N2M3N2N2M3N2M3N1N3N2M3N2M3N1O2M3N2N2N2M2O2N2N2N2N1O2N2N2N3M2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2N2M3N1O2N2N2N101N2N2N1O2N2O0O2N2N2N101N2N1O2O1N1O2N2N101N2N1O2O0O2N1O2N1O2O0O2N1O2N1O2N1O2O0O2N1O2N100O2N1O2O0O2N101N1O101N1O101N1O101N1O2O0O1O2N100O2N1O101N1O2N100O2N101N1O101N1O2N101N2N101N1O2O0O2N2O0O2N101N1O2O0O2N101N1O2O0O101N1O2O0O1O2O0O1O2N100O2N1O101N1O101N101N1O101N100O2N101N100O2N101N1O2O0O1O2O0O2N1O101N1O1O2O0O1O2N1O100O2O0O100O100O100O2O0O100O10000O101N100O10000O10000O101N10000O100O10000O10000O100O10000O100O10000O10000O10000000000O10000000O0100000000O100000000O01000000000000O1000O1000O1000000O100000000O1000000O1000000O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O100O2O0O100O101N101N1O101N101N100O2O0O2O0O101N100O2O0O101N101N100O2N100O2N101N100O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O101N101O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O000O2O0O2O0O2O000O2O0O2O0O2O0O101N101O0O2O0O2O0O2N101N2O0O2N101N2O0O2N2O0O2O1N101N2N101N2O0O2O1N101N2O0O2O1N101N101N2O0O2O0O2O0O2O1N101N101N101N101N1O2O0O2N2O0O2N1O2O0O2N2N101N1O2O1N1O2O1N1O2O1N1O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O0O2O001N101N2N101N101N101N101N2O0O2N2O1N1O2N2N2O1N2N1O2N2N2N2O1N2N1O2N2N2O1N2N2N2N2N101N1O101N101N1O1O2O0O2N100O2N101N1O2N100O2N1O2N101N2N2N2N2N2M3N2N3M2N2N2N3M2M4M3M2N3L4M2N3L3N3M2M3N3L3N2N2N2M3N2N2N1O2N2N2N2N2N3M2N2N2N2N2M3N3M2N2N2N2M3N3M3L4L4L4L4L6J6J6J6J6J5J7H8G9G:F9G9H9E:G>A`0@`0@`0[Oe0ZOe0WOf]nS9'}, 'area': 414986, 'bbox': [955, 125, 696, 768], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2335, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': {'size': [2941, 4904], 'counts': 'b__k0Y3Xg2k1kNR1lNo0TOl0_Oa0@>F6G:F:E: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>B:E;F:D=D<D=B>B>B>B>B>Ag0oNP`kR;'}, 'area': 371290, 'bbox': [306, 235, 644, 732], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2336, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[1292, 1003, 1222, 1479, 1232, 1937, 1467, 2048, 1809, 2071, 2054, 1923, 2257, 1683, 2142, 1239, 1842, 1045, 1467, 948]], 'area': 903055.5, 'bbox': [1222, 948, 1035, 1123], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2337, 'image_id': 43, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[1250, 1225, 1269, 1036, 1167, 971, 978, 939, 682, 1087, 543, 1299, 562, 1553, 488, 1923, 659, 2048, 774, 2089, 1061, 2052, 1213, 2020, 1222, 1900]], 'area': 713928.0, 'bbox': [488, 939, 781, 1150], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2338, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 1, 'segmentation': [[377, 321, 142, 453, 156, 782, 401, 965, 711, 796, 726, 448]], 'area': 279802.0, 'bbox': [142, 321, 584, 644], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2339, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[3915, 358, 419, 386]], 'area': 161734, 'bbox': [3915, 358, 419, 386], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2340, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[2810, 340, 564, 456]], 'area': 257184, 'bbox': [2810, 340, 564, 456], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2341, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[1954, 382, 555, 419]], 'area': 232545, 'bbox': [1954, 382, 555, 419], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2342, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[862, 387, 654, 409]], 'area': 267486, 'bbox': [862, 387, 654, 409], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2343, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[448, 1417, 381, 282]], 'area': 107442, 'bbox': [448, 1417, 381, 282], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2344, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[1135, 1403, 555, 343]], 'area': 190365, 'bbox': [1135, 1403, 555, 343], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2345, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[2193, 1379, 621, 358]], 'area': 222318, 'bbox': [2193, 1379, 621, 358], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2346, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[3285, 1375, 550, 296]], 'area': 162800, 'bbox': [3285, 1375, 550, 296], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2347, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[4240, 1393, 480, 349]], 'area': 167520, 'bbox': [4240, 1393, 480, 349], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2348, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[3859, 2250, 574, 371]], 'area': 212954, 'bbox': [3859, 2250, 574, 371], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2349, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[2810, 2278, 635, 428]], 'area': 271780, 'bbox': [2810, 2278, 635, 428], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2350, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[1822, 2316, 729, 329]], 'area': 239841, 'bbox': [1822, 2316, 729, 329], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2351, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[890, 2330, 758, 315]], 'area': 238770, 'bbox': [890, 2330, 758, 315], 'iscrowd': 0}
{'id': 2352, 'image_id': 64, 'category_id': 2, 'segmentation': [[274, 2334, 386, 269]], 'area': 103834, 'bbox': [274, 2334, 386, 269], 'iscrowd': 0}
```

Edit @Tenacious B
I noticed I was doing two thing wrongly, first the bounding box is not a polygon. Had to convert it in the following manner:

```
import shapely.geometry

#convert bounding boxes to polygons
for i in d["annotations"]:
  #Only the segmentations that are bounding boxes
  if i["segmentation"] == None:
    bbox=tuple(i["bbox"])
    print(i["bbox"])

    #Retrieve polygon from bbox through shapely.geometry.box, format was 
    polygon=shapely.geometry.box(*(bbox[0],bbox[1],bbox[0]+bbox[2], bbox[1]+bbox[3]), ccw=True)    ))
    K=str(polygon.wkt).split("POLYGON ((")[-1].split("))")[0].split(',')
    polygon=[]
    for m in K:
      for p in m.split(" "):
        if p:
          polygon.append(int(p))

    polygon=[polygon]
    print(polygon)

    i["segmentation"] = polygon

#Resulting in proper polygons:
[4063, 2452, 474, 207]
[[4537, 2452, 4537, 2659, 4063, 2659, 4063, 2452, 4537, 2452]]
[3268, 1553, 395, 288]
[[3663, 1553, 3663, 1841, 3268, 1841, 3268, 1553, 3663, 1553]]
```

Also I forgot to call the new .json file created for visualizing and training. With these changes, visualization works properly. However training is still noticing that my newly created segmentation polygons are in fact bounding boxes. I have checked the entire .json file meticulously but see no references to them being not polygons.

```
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/data/detection_utils.py", line 389, in annotations_to_instances
    masks = PolygonMasks(segms)
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/structures/masks.py", line 288, in __init__
    process_polygons(polygons_per_instance) for polygons_per_instance in polygons
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/structures/masks.py", line 288, in <listcomp>
    process_polygons(polygons_per_instance) for polygons_per_instance in polygons
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/structures/masks.py", line 278, in process_polygons
    "Got '{}' instead.".format(type(polygons_per_instance))
ValueError: Cannot create polygons: Expect a list of polygons per instance. Got '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>' instead.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 198, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/data/common.py", line 43, in __getitem__
    data = self._map_func(self._dataset[cur_idx])
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/utils/serialize.py", line 23, in __call__
    return self._obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/data/dataset_mapper.py", line 176, in __call__
    annos, image_shape, mask_format=self.instance_mask_format
  File "/content/detectron2_repo/detectron2/data/detection_utils.py", line 393, in annotations_to_instances
    ) from e
ValueError: Failed to use mask_format=='polygon' from the given annotations!
```

The .json file with converted segmentations can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YXmA0rg2svOW-IDo13b20pnSmuXsfHk3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: the key error would seem to indicate there is at least one dictionary/json object that does not contain the `'segmentation'` key (regardless of the `None`), maybe try `masks = [x.get("segmentation") for x in annos]`, should return `[..., None, ...]` if the key is not found